# Default Add To Wishlist is not appearing in product detail page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, wishlist, addtowishlist

Move to wishlist option is appearing in cart page but in product detail page Add to wishlist is not appearing. In the backend, it didn't disabled wishlist options but still, it is not displaying in product detail page.

Comment: maybe Your specific theme doesnt contain it on product page ?

Comment: how to add in product page? Please give some eg

Comment: Try to check the Core template files for PDP and find out if the core file having the code for adding item into wishlist. If yes, then you just need to copy that piece of code from core to your theme file. Then I guess it should work.